# how to display our custom profile link when drupal installation setup

Tags: installation

I'm working on custom profile making in drupal 8. That's my first custom profile. It's completly done with module installation & entity created. But when I'm running installation it doesn't ask me for selecting profile like standard, minimal, custom profile.

How could I do that please help.